# Resolve links in include file

Tags: php, hyperlink, include

I have a site located at http://www.mySite.com. My html/PHP pages are located at http://www.mySite.com/index.php I have created a 'tabs' include file located at http://www.mySite.com/includes/tabs.html. And all is grand!

But I have started to need a bit more functionality and have added pre-coded pages/packages, like a blog. These packages are located in their own directories like http://www.mySite.com/blog.

The problem is the from the new package directories the links in the tabs include are no longer pointing to the correct URL because of the directory change. I understand why this is happening but cannot figure out a work around other than maintaining 2 separate tabs files, which seems wrong.

I had a very similar question that dealt with the css links and solved by adding a slash before the stylesheet path in the stylesheet link. Unfortunately it does not work in this situation also because in the different directory the include is '../includes/tabs.html'.

The tabs link is a standard html link:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Again in my root directory files it works fine but if I put a file in a new directory like "http://www.mysite.com/newDir/index.php" the tabs are pointing to "http://www.mysite.com/newDir/tabURL.php" not "http://www.mysite.com/index.php".

Thank you again for your time,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is update your links in the tab.html file to use absolute paths instead of relative paths.

```
<li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: On my local server it takes me all the wat to http://www.localhost/ instead of http://www.localhost/mysite.com. Any way around that?

Comment: Set up a local domain for your site. In your HOSTS file, add the line `127.0.0.1  mysite.local`, setup your server to use mysite.local as the site domain name, and access it through that domain instead of localhost.

Comment: Solved! Probably will solve anohter set of issues when trying to install 3rd party apps also. Great many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

try including the tabs file using the full path on server no in your site directory e.g. `www/mysite/includes/tabs.html`

Comment: The problem isn't that he can't include the tabs.html file, but that the links in that file are going to the wrong location.

Comment: I am not speaking of putting this for url. I got confused because he is saying including tabs I tough he uses php include function